# My code is not running properly not printing all the rows it should

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int i,j,n,m;

    printf("enter the numbr of rows : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    m=(2*n)+1;
    printf("%d, %d",n,m);
    for(i=0;i<=m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            if(i==n)
            {
                printf("*");
            }
            else 
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
        } 

        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            if((i+j)>=m)
               break;
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My code is not running properly not printing all the rows it should. It is the code to print a full arrow like

```
     *
     **
********
     **
     *
```

its just an example.

Comment: And what *does* it print? And have you tried to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program?

Comment: @Mohammad Sanaullah What does "the numbr of rows" mean? that is what do n and m mean?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is:

```
m=(2*n)+1;
```

It needs to be

```
m=(2*n);
```

see: [Online gcc compiler example draw arrow](https://onlinegdb.com/H1gogfIHYz)

Comment: m value is set 2n+1 it should print m rows for 2 it should print 5 rows 3 for 7 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

https://onlinegdb.com/rk9U4nUFf

It got fixed!!!  i was running the loop one time less so it was running but not printing anything as the last loop was skipping a loop which it should not. Above is the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {

    int i,j,n,m;

    printf("enter the numbr of rows : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    m=(2*n);
    printf("%d, %d",n,m);
    for(i=0;i<=m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            if(i==n)
            {
                printf("*");
            }
            else 
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
        } 

        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            if((i+j)>=m)
               break;
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Source Link: https://www.onlinegdb.com/H1gogfIHYz